# How to pass bindingContext to top-level TabView

Tags: nativescript

I need to localize TabViewItem **title** when TabView used as main navigation with Frame items (app generated with Nativescript Sidekick -> General -> TypeScript -> Tab Navigation).

For localization I use [nativescript-localize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-localize) plugin, with next initialization in `app.ts` for use in template:

```ts
import * as app from "tns-core-modules/application";
import { localize } from "nativescript-localize";

app.getResources().L = localize;

app.run({ moduleName: "app-root" });
```

And `app-root.xml` has next content:

```xml
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom">
    <TabViewItem title="{{ L('catalog') }}">
        <Frame defaultPage="pages/catalog/catalog-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>

    <TabViewItem title="{{ L('notifications') }}">
        <Frame defaultPage="pages/notifications/notifications-page"></Frame>
    </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

If I use next construction `{{ L('catalog') }}` in final pages with initialized `bindingContext` then everything works as expected. But in top-level TabView this construction does not work. I think it is because not initialized `bindingContext`, but how can I initialize it for top-level TabView.

For testing and prototyping, I create Playground - [top level TabView](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=8PFi3y&v=2). In this Playground instead [nativescript-localize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-localize) plugin I use the function which return text, and as you can see it successfully executed in `home-page.xml`, but does not executed in `app-root.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's an edge case bug, it seems the expressions are not processed until a `bindingContext` is set.

Just declaring `bindingContext` attribute in XML seems to solve the issue

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom" bindingContext="">
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=8PFi3y&v=3)

Comment: Great! Your hint about set empty value to `bindingContext` with the property of `TabView` works.
Do you think I need to create the issue for [NativeScript](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript).

Comment: Yes, I think it should be reported. At least the documents could be updated saying it's mandatory for application resources to work.